# why is .net core 5 webapi xml serializer different that swaggers serializer?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger, xml-serialization, swagger-ui

I enable the xml serializer in my .net core 5 web api:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
        .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
        //.AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()
        .AddJsonOptions(o =>
        {
            o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
            o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter());
        });

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = $"Routing Evaluator Package Demo Service ({appSettings.Environment})", Version = "v1" });
    });
}
```

My controller takes a parameter

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<TestResponse> Post(TestRequest request)
{
   ...
}
```

And my model looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
//[DataContract]
public class TestRequest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The message addressing information
    /// </summary>
    //[DataMember]
    [XmlArray("Items")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Item")]
    public Items Items { get; set; }
    
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Items")]
//[CollectionDataContract(Name = "Items")]
public class Items : List<Item>
{
}

[Serializable]
//[DataContract]
[XmlRoot("Item")]
public class Item 
{
    public string key {get;set;}
    public string value {get;set;}
}
```

If I manually serialize an instance of my object, I get results like this:

**Object Instance:**

```
var request = new TestRequest()
{   
    Items = new Items()
    {
        new Item() {key = "A", value="1"},
        new Item() {key = "B", value="2"},
        new Item() {key = "C", value="3"}
    }
};
```

**Serialization:**

```
using (var str = new MemoryStream())
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(DemoService.ServiceModels.EvaluationRequest));
    ser.Serialize(str, request);
    str.Flush();
    str.Position = 0;
    _output.WriteLine(str.ReadAsString());
}
```

**Results:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <key>A</key>
            <value>1</value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <key>B</key>
            <value>2</value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <key>C</key>
            <value>3</value>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</TestRequest>
```

If I browse to the swagger page,  the example it shows is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestRequest>
    <Items>
        <key>A</key>
        <value>1</value>
    </Items>
</TestRequest>
```

The sample it supplied is incorrect.  It appears that the serializer that swagger is using is not the same as the serializer that the web api is using as specfied by AddXmlSerializerFormatters.   Do I need to configure swagger somehow to make them match?

Answer (score 0):

Your model is wrong, it should be like below

```
[Serializable]
public class TestRequest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The message addressing information
    /// </summary>
    //[DataMember]
    [XmlArray("Items")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Item")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    
}

[Serializable]
public class Item 
{
    public string key {get;set;}
    public string value {get;set;}
}
```